# Firebase/GeoFire - Most popular item at location

Tags: firebase, geolocation, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am currently in the evaluation process for a database that should serve as a backend for a mobile application.

---

Right now I am looking at **Firebase**, and for now I like it really much.

---

It is a requirement to have the possibility to fetch the

1. **most popular items**
2. at a **certain location**
3. (possibly in the future: additionally for a certain time range that would be an attribute of the item)

from the database.

---

So naturally I stumbled upon GeoFire that provides location based query possibilities for Firebase.

Unfortunately - at least as far as I understood - there is no possibility to order the results by an attribute other than the distance. (correct me if I am wrong).

So what do I do if I am not interested in the distance (I only want to have items in a certain radius, no matter how far from the center) but in the popularity factor (e.g. for the sake of simplicity a simple number that symbolizes popularity)?

**IMPORTANT:**
Filtering/Sorting on the client-side is not an option (or at least the least preferred one), as the result set could potentially grow to an infinite amount.

---

First version of the application will be for android, so the Firebase Java Client Library would be used in the first step.

---

Are there possibilities to solve this or is Firebase out of the race and not the right candidate for the job?

Comment: There is no way to add an extra condition to the server-side query of Geofire. Well... strictly speaking you could find a way to extend the magic of Geohashes to add a third number (in addition to lat and lon) into the mix. But while possible, I doubt it's feasible for most of us.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick response. Thats sad, I would have really liked to use Firebase as a backend, but this query unfortunately is crucial. I will see if I still find another solution (e.g. use an intermediate server that does the heavy stuff before sending the answer to a client request for those special use cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to add an extra condition to the server-side query of Geofire.

The query model of the Firebase database allows filtering only on a single property. Geofire already performs a seemingly impossible feat of filtering on both latitude and longitude. It does this through the magic of [Geohashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), which combine latitude and longitude into a single string.

Strictly speaking you could find a way to extend the magic of Geohashes to add a third number into the mix. But while possible, I doubt it's feasible for most of us.