# How can I use a GeoQuery to sort by both location and certain value? (Android)

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

This is a Geoquery for Firestore: https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android
But it doesn't allow for further sorting.
 I want to sort by the nearest and most famous users, how could i do such a thing? Are there any other possible libraries?

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/b52ogt/how_can_i_use_the_geofirestore_library_to_sort_by/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geofire already does something seemingly impossible on Firestore: it performs a range query on two values (lat and lon). It does this by creating a geohash value, which combines the latitude and longitude into a single value, that can be used to select a range of documents that are close to each other.

To allow additionally select on the range of another field, you'd have to find a way to combine the value of that other field into the Geohash value. It essentially means you have to find a way to express the importance of fame (your additional property) as a function of location (the distance), and compute a single field value based on that. While this may technically possible, I doubt anyone has ever done it.

To learn how filtering on location works (and why adding an extra field is not as simple as it may seem), have a look at:

- the [video of my talk on geofiltering on Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q)
- Jeff's much more concise [Realtime GeoQueries With Firestore](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/geolocation-query-in-firestore-realtime/) video and article
- [Firebase/GeoFire - Most popular item at location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953512/firebase-geofire-most-popular-item-at-location)

Comment: Will Firestore's eventual native geoquerying use geohashes and work like GeoFire or will it work differently (i.e. using Google S2 Geometry)?

Comment: Nobody has started work on this yet, so there's no sense speculating on how it will work.

Comment: This means that it is not possible (or at least, very hard...) to combine any 'where' with a geoquery in Firebase or Firestore, is this correct?

Comment: It depends on the other `where`. Adding an additional equality check is possible, although I don't think any of the existing libraries allow that in their API. Adding an additional range check will indeed be  much harder.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. So I understand that it is possible, but does Firestore allow that? 

For example, is it possible in Firestore a query such as: 
db.collection('places')
  .orderBy("geoHash")
  .where('geoHash', '>=', range.lower)
  .where('geoHash', '<=', range.upper)
  .where("cities", "array-contains", "rome")
  .limit(15).get()
 
I can ask a new question if necessary of course

Comment: Yeah, that looks possible. If you run into problems, that'd be a good moment to post a new question. :)