# Workaround to query on field with filter on a different field [Firestore]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data), If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field.

As such, the follow query is invalid since we are filtering by "population" and sorting by "country"

```
citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("country")
```

Apart from downloading the entire filtered collection and sorting it locally, is there a **workaround** for this issue.

I am open to even use any 3rd party software to achieve this query without having to download the entire filtered collection.

I would also be grateful if someone could point me to a place where this issue is discussed with further information.

Answer (score 0):

> Apart from downloading the entire filtered collection and sorting it locally, is there a workaround for this issue.

No, there is not.  It's a hard limitation of the database.  What you see in the documentation is fact.  You might want to [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60888667) for more info.  Quoted:

> This is inherent about Firestore's query model, so it may help to know more about that.. It's performance guarantees mean that it must always be able to stream the results from the database once it's found the starting point for your query. Re-ordering an unknown number of results would make it impossible to always satisfy that performance guarantee, so is not a supported operation.